# Installing GuestAddition

Tags: guest-additions

I have installed Ubuntu server version 14. 04.3 on window 8.1 host . I am using Linux version.My problem is that for over a month i have I have been unable to install guest-additions so that I can use shared folders.This is after having browsed many pages where suggestions on this were given.

I have install the VboxGuestAdditiond .iso file at the command prompt and mounted same in my home directory. I was able access the installer and initiate the installation and I have the following error messages in the process:

1. the headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following module compilation fails then this could be the reason.
2. Building share folder module fails(look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find what went wrong).

Please some one assit

Comment: Please provide version details for the linux system and  virtualbox. Normally though the guest additions would be installed by first selecting that option in the "Devices" menu, then running the install file as root.

Comment: Thanks ,but  I have already tried to do so through the ''Devices'' menu as you said and got  the error that the file VBoxGuesAddions.iso  is not found in the folder ''program file\VBox......'. That is why I went for the other option of using the command prompt

Comment: Using virtualbox on an ubuntu host, the very first step is to start virtualbox with the extension pack as argument so as to install that extension into virtualbox, and make the additions iso available from the devices menu. I'm not sure about how this is done on a widnows host, and maybe you're past this step anyhow, but I thought it worth mentioning, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

As @RalphRönnquist already mentioned, you have run the install as root (i.e. sudo). You however also need the headers and build environment. You get those through:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then try to install the guest additions again:

```
$ sudo /path/to/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Because you've installed `Ubuntu Server` and not the desktop version of `Ubuntu`, the installation will fail on `X`. It should be something similar to `Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System`.
This is normal and nothing to worry about (as long as that is the only thing the installer complains about).

Comment: Thank you, but I have earlier on install the the headers and the build environment, though not using the syntax above before the final step.I will repeat in the way you suggest with the hope it will solve my problem.